# utorrent file: mark as complete even if uncomplete

Tags: utorrent

I've downloaded 90% of a torrent and the remaining 10% will never be downloaded, however I am happy with the downloaded 90%, so I'd like to mark it as complete, and put it alongside the rest of completed files, if possible.

I imagine utorrent relies on files being complete and an exact copy of one another, so what could I do, at least, to mark it as complete and remove it from the "Downloading" tab?

Maybe moving it from its location?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the torrent files location and removed the torrent in the program.

Comment: Why those downvotes? They aren't helpful at all but thanks.